# Como selecionar strings que comecem com uma determinada palavra

Tags: r, string, dataframe

Estou manipulando um dataframe no `R v.3.5.2` e gostaria de saber como crio uma nova variável chamada `ES_1_4` que tenha apenas as linhas da coluna `Pathways` que tem como valor a string com início `REACTOME_`. Entretanto, esse é apenas o início da string, mas depois de `REACTOME_` vem outras palavras diversas. Como eu faria para indicar que a string não termina no `_` de `REACTOME` e que o que vem depois pode ser qualquer coisa?

Tinha tentado assim:

```
ES_1_4 = ES_1_3[ES_1_3$Pathways == "REACTOME_", ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize a função `grep`. Ela permite realizar filtros como este que tu deseja, baseado apenas em um trecho de string:

```
ES_1_4 = ES_1_3[grep("REACTOME_", ES_1_3$Pathways), ]
```

No comando acima, o novo objeto `ES_1_4` terá todas as linhas de `ES_1_3` que possuam a string `REACTOME_` em algum lugar da coluna `Pathways`.

Answer (score 2):

Para que a expressão regular encontre apenas no inicio da linha use  `^` no início da expressão. Assim é possível:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ES_1_3 <- data_frame(
  Pathways = c("REACTOME_final", "inicio_REACTOME_"),
  outra_coluna = 1:2
)

ES_1_3[grep("^REACTOME_", ES_1_3$Pathways), ]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   Pathways       outra_coluna
#>   <chr>                 <int>
#> 1 REACTOME_final            1

ES_1_3[str_starts(ES_1_3$Pathways, "REACTOME_"), ]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   Pathways       outra_coluna
#>   <chr>                 <int>
#> 1 REACTOME_final            1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Desde a [versão mais recente](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/02/stringr-1-4-0/) do [stringr](/questions/tagged/stringr) (1.4.0), é possível usar a função `str_starts()`, que aparece na segunda solução. Usando ela não há mais a necessidade de lembrar o símbolo de regex que demarca o início da linha.

Note que o resultado das duas soluções acima é o resultado solicitado na pergunta (apenas casos em que comecem com a palavra) e difere do resultado da resposta do @MarcusNunes, que encontra a palavra em qualquer posição da *string*.

```r
ES_1_3[grep("REACTOME_", ES_1_3$Pathways), ]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Pathways         outra_coluna
#>   <chr>                   <int>
#> 1 REACTOME_final              1
#> 2 inicio_REACTOME_            2
```